# Manipular arquivo .txt em Ruby e pupular BD?

Tags: ruby, postgresql

Preciso abrir um arquivo .txt qualquer que tenha um sequência de strings separadas por  ";" e preciso colocar a cada ";" em um vetor para depois criar um laço e inserir no banco.

O que eu tenho:

```
require 'pg'
require 'active_record'


 = File.open('teste.txt')
f_lines = f.read.split(";")
```

#### Conexão com o banco

```
conn = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter => 'postgresql',
                                                :username => 'root', 
                                                :password => "123",
                                                :host => "127.0.0.1",
                                                :database => "db")

#query = "insert into students (name, registration, room, password) values "+ vetor[]
#simulated = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```

PS.: Meu arquivo .txt terá várias linhas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você estava bem no caminho certo, faltou só o pulo do gato srsrs

Vou utilizar um arquivo de entrada para demonstração

**grupos.txt**

```
'Administradores'; 'adm'; true
'Redatores'; 'red'; false
'Editores'; 'edt'; false
'Leitores'; 'lei'; false
```

**Aqui a conexão que você já fez:**

```
require 'pg'
require 'active_record'

file = File.open('grupos.txt')

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter => 'postgresql',
                                                :username => 'root', 
                                                :password => "123",
                                                :host => "127.0.0.1",
                                                :database => "db")
```

**E o pulo do gato:**

```
file.each_line do |line|
  values = line.split(';').join(',')
  insert_sql = "insert into grupos (nome, slug, padrao) values ( #{values} )"
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute insert_sql
end
```

**Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OTIMIZANDO**

Caso seu arquivo não seja pequeno, vale muito a pena usar `transaction` , esse mesmo exemplo com 1000 linhas demorou **26.221072s** para rodar, utilizando `transaction` levou apenas  **0.343375s**

**Exemplo com transaction:**

```
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.transaction do
    file.each_line do |line|
      values = line.split(';').join(',')
      insert_sql = "insert into grupos (nome, slug, padrao) values ( #{values} )"
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute insert_sql
    end
  end
```

Comment: Caaaaaaaaara, Perfeito!!!!Muito Obrigado, ajudou muito mesmo

Comment: Opa que bom que ajudou @Juliano, se a resposta resolveu seu problema marque como resposta. Grande abraço. Precisando estamos ai!

Comment: Boaa @Juliano :D